# Child routes inside lazy loaded module not activated

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 7 application with multiple lazy loaded feature modules. My main routing module configuration looks like this

```
{
    path: '',
    component: HomeLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'competitions',
        loadChildren: './competitions/competitions.module#competitionsModule'
      }
    ]
}
```

I can successfully navigate to `/competitions` which will list competitions and render everything in my main un-named `<router-outlet>` in my `HomeLayoutComponent`.

My routing for the `CompetitionsModule` looks like

```
{
    path: '',
    component: CompetitionsPageComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
},
{
    path: ':id',
    component: CompetitionDetailsPageComponent,
    children: [
    {
        path: 'participants',
        component: ParticipantsComponent,
        outlet: 'competitionDetailsContent',
    }
    ]
},
{
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: ''
}
```

I can navigate to `/competition/123` to view the details of that specific competition, but that's where it ends. Inside my `CompetitionsDetailsPageComponent` and it's corresponding template, I have a named outlet that should display components depending on tab selections. As an example, I should be able to click a tab and use a router link to display participants of the competition with the route `/competitions/123/participants`. With my current routing configuration, the result is that I get redirected back to `/competitions`.

I've tried adding the `:id` as a child route to `''` without getting that to work, and I've scanned through all possible solutions on SO without any luck. I should mention that my named `<router-outlet name="competitionDetailsContent">` is inside an `*ngIf`, but I'm unsure if it affects my routing.

I've tried following `routerLink` alternatives:

`[routerLink]="['', { outlets: { competitionDetailsContent: ['participants'] } }]`

and `[routerLink]="['./participants', {outlets: competitionDetailsContent}]"` with no success.

What is the proper way to set this routing up? All examples I find only refer to non-lazy loaded modules.

Comment: What does your route activation code look like? Do you have a `routerLink` on your tabs? What does it look like?

Comment: Also, there are some bugs/issues with lazy loaded modules and auxiliary (named) router outlets: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10981. Could you achieve your goal using another child outlet instead of a named outlet? I have a tabs example and I used simple child routes (not named routes).

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at this @DeborahK! I've added my `routerLinks` to my original question. Perhaps I can remove the named outlet and use a regular outlet instead, I will look into that. Do you perhaps have a link or code sample of your working tabs example? (I take the opportunity to also thank you for your courses on PluralSight, they helped me and taught me all the fundamentals needed when getting into AngularJS and later on Angular!).

Comment: I walk through how to build tabs in my "Angular Routing" course. I'll paste some code in an answer.

Comment: @DeborahK i am already on a component of lazy loaded module and now i want to goto some other component (in same lazy loaded module) but routerLink is not working. for e.g. in member module I am at login route and i want to go to forgotPassword route, but when i write `routerLink="forgotPassword"` the route becomes `/members/login/forgotPassword` rather than `members/forgotPassword`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tabs are children of the edit page:

[image]

I built my tabs with child routes, not auxiliary (named) routes.

Here is an example of my route configuration:

```
RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProductListComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: ProductDetailComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':id/edit',
    component: ProductEditComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'info', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'info', component: ProductEditInfoComponent },
      { path: 'tags', component: ProductEditTagsComponent }
    ]
  }
])
```

]

Here is the ProductEditComponent HTML with the tabs and `routerLink` directives:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    {{pageTitle}}
  </div>

  <div class="card-body"
       *ngIf="product">
    <div class="wizard">
      <a [routerLink]="['info']"
         routerLinkActive="active">
        Basic Information<span [ngClass]="{'fa fa-exclamation': !isValid('info')}"></span>
      </a>
      <a [routerLink]="['tags']"
         routerLinkActive="active">
        Search Tags<span [ngClass]="{'fa fa-exclamation': !isValid('tags')}"></span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

    <div class="row mb-2">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary mr-3"
                style="width:80px"
                type="button"
                title="Save your entered data"
                [disabled]="!isValid()"
                (click)="saveProduct()">
          Save
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-3"
                style="width:80px"
                type="button"
                title="Cancel your edits"
                [routerLink]="['/products']">
          Cancel
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-warning"
                style="width:80px"
                type="button"
                title="Delete this product"
                (click)="deleteProduct()">
          Delete
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can find the complete example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing

(Though it is currently in Angular v2. I am working on migrating it to v7 as we speak.)

Comment: I ended up doing it like like this with a few modifications to fit my need and got it to work as desired! I don't know why I got stuck on the idea of using auxiliary routes! Thank you!